# position the markers in highcharts to custom coordinate

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am teaching myself highcharts and I ran into a situation where

1)I need to position the markers in a spline to a coordinate set of my choice i.e., I want to align the markers horizontally next to each other above the chart instead of positioning them on the graph.

2)I need to able to draw dotted lines from the x axis labels to the markers

3)I need to show the `[data]` inside the markers

[image: highcharts graph]

I tried searching for it in the highcharts API and googled it as well. Couldn't find a solution.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be done in two ways,

1. use a dummy series with scatter plot type and use those images as markers like in here http://jsfiddle.net/SkRDH/
2. use `renderer.image()` like in here http://jsfiddle.net/H53LF/

My advice is to go with the scatter chart approach

I hope this will help you to solve your problem

Comment: Thank you! How about the dotted line present in between and the circles present above the labels on the x-axis. Also how do I show the data inside the circle. Any ideas ?

Comment: thanks again ! I guess I can tag you in any question related to highCharts and get a response from you!

Comment: I think that's not a proper way in stack overflow. this is a open forum

Comment: I know that! I only meant I can always get answers when you are around!

Comment: Could you possibly take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168845/custom-highcharts-change-the-height-of-plotlines-show-the-marker-value-by-de